# I can't delete my file in my host with my php script?

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink, rmdir

I use this code to delete my file and folder in my host script successfully deleted folder but script cant delete my file in host can anyone explain my mistake or any other tips?
This is my code:

```
    <?php

$fileArray = array(
    "./dat/1.jpg",
    "./dat/img/second.3gp",
    "./dat/img/third.mov"
);
$directory = array(
    "./2014/jun/game/game/icevi/",
    "./2013/dec/game/game/icelage/"

);

foreach ($fileArray as $value) {
    if (file_exists($value)) {
        unlink($value);
    }
    }
    foreach ($directory as $value) {
    if (is_dir($value)) {
        rmdir($value);
    }
    }

?>
```

Host default permission for folder 755,
and for file is 644. I change file permission to any other but stilll it does not work.

Comment: do you see any errors ?

Comment: when set else for it show link not found but it exist

Comment: try var_dump(file_exists($value)); let me know the result

Comment: show me only "bool(false)"

Comment: looks like relative paths are incorrect, please check them, look where is your executable file

Comment: no,paths are correct whene i create a custom file in 'dat' place like '1.txt' and set address to "./dat/1.txt" script successfully delete it but cant find and delete other file